# IIS Express Worker Process preventing Visual Studio 2022 project from building

Tags: visual-studio-2022, iis-express

I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution that includes VB class libraries and an MVC Web Application. When I modify a library referenced by my web app, and attempt to run/debug, Visual Studio cannot build the modified library, becasue the IIS Express Worker Process that is running from the previous debug session is still running, and has the .dll file locked.
How do I configure Visual Studio 2022 to kill IIS Express and/or the IIS Express Worker Process when I stop debugging? I believe that when debugging is stopped, previous versions of Visual Studio properly killed the instance of IIS Express that it launched.

Build Error:
Could not copy "obj\x64\Debug\xxx.dll" to "..\Build\64\Debug\xxx.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "IIS Express Worker Process (PID Number)"

I've tried toggling all the hot reload options I could find, as I believe the 'hot reload' term has replaced the 'edit and continue' term used in previous VS options.